# How do I join 3 tables where a given ID may be present in one or more with only one row per ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got 3 tables.

`Table1` Fields

- EmployeeId
- Year1Sales

`Table2` Fields

- EmployeeId
- Year2Sales

`Table3` Fields

- EmployeeId
- Year3Sales

What I want as output is a single table with one row per `EmployeeId`.

OutputTable Fields

- EmployeeId
- Year1Sales
- Year2Sales
- Year3Sales

The problem is a given employee may only be present in one of these tables. I tried using a `FULL JOIN` as below, but I get multiple rows per employee if they aren't present in all 3 tables.

```
SELECT COALESCE(T1.EmployeeId, T2.EmployeeId, T3.EmployeeId),
       Year1Sales,
       Year2Sales,
       Year3Sales,
FROM Table1 AS T1 FULL JOIN Table2 AS T2 ON T1.EmployeeId = T2.EmployeeId
                  FULL JOIN Table3 AS T3 ON T1.EmployeeId = T3.EmployeeId
```

In `Table1`, `Table2` and `Table3` there is only one row per `EmployeeId`.

If, for example, an employee is only present in years 2 and 3 I get the following incorrect output:

```
EmployeeId     Year1Sales      Year2Sales     Year3Sales
1                NULL             1000           NULL
1                NULL             NULL           2000
```

How can I join these 3 tables together and only have one line per employee?

Comment: We need a [mre] i.e. sample data which illustrates the problem ideally as DDL+DML.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps left join them all onto the union of all emplyee ids:

```
WITH all AS(
  SELECT EmployeeId FROM T1 UNION SELECT EmployeeId FROM T2 UNION SELECT EmployeeId FROM T3 )

SELECT * 
FROM
  all
  LEFT JOIN T1 ON all.EmployeeId = T1.EmployeeID
  LEFT JOIN T2 ON all.EmployeeId = T2.EmployeeID
  LEFT JOIN T3 ON all.EmployeeId = T3.EmployeeID
```

If the emps will be present multiple times in a table, group them before you join:

```
FROM
  all
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT EmployeeID, SUM(Year1Sales) as Year1Sales FROM T1 GROUP BY EmployeeID) T1 ON all.EmployeeId = T1.EmployeeID
  ...
```

Comment: Why query the tables a second time, it seems completely unnecessary?

Answer (score 0):

There is another approach.

```
select EmployeeId, SUM(Year1Sales) As Year1Sales, SUM(Year2Sales) As Year2Sales, SUM(Year3Sales) As Year3Sales
from (
select EmployeeId, Year1Sales, Null Year2Sales, Null Year3Sales from Table1
union All
select EmployeeId, Null Year1Sales, Year2Sales, Null Year3Sales from Table2
union All
select EmployeeId, Null Year1Sales, Null Year2Sales, Year3Sales from Table3) As T
group by EmployeeId
order by EmployeeId;
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to coalesce the first `FULL JOIN` before you join the third table**

```sql
SELECT
  ISNULL(T1.EmployeeId, T3.EmployeeId) EmployeeId,
  T1.Year1Sales,
  T1.Year2Sales,
  T3.Year3Sales
FROM (
    SELECT
      ISNULL(T1.EmployeeId, T2.EmployeeId) EmployeeId,
      T1.Year1Sales,
      T2.Year2Sales
    FROM Table1 AS T1
    FULL JOIN Table2 AS T2 ON T1.EmployeeId = T2.EmployeeId
) T1
FULL JOIN Table3 AS T3 ON T1.EmployeeId = T3.EmployeeId;
```

What is happening here is that the join condition is not being fulfilled

```
ON T1.EmployeeId = T3.EmployeeId
```

---

What happens is that `T1` has no matching ID, so `T3` is being pushed through unmatched.

You could do `ON T3.EmployeeId IN (T1.EmployeeId, T2.EmployeeId)` which looks simpler, but usually performs worse.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3ca985e0d6e2f882cf7d378ffb5c0b5f)

> I note that having similar data in three separate tables is itself a design problem. It should probably be one big table.